# How to access Azure B2C openId protected API by multiple client Application

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, openid, azure-ad-b2c

I secure my nodeJs API with Azure B2C. I have two web application which accesses my API.

the two Web application has its own application Id in Azure B2C. Also, those can generate access_token with B2C.

But when I validate those access_token in my API I have to put application id of the web application witch generate the access_token as an **audience**.

But the audience does not support array. I can only put one application id.

How do I solve this?

If I secure an API with B2C I only can make requests from one web application?

Comment: Based upon Chris’s answer, are you sure you are getting access tokens?  Maybe you are receiving id_token’s?

Answer (score 1):

The audience (`aud`) claim for an access token identifies **the intended recipient** (i.e. the API application) of the access token.

At a high-level, you must:

1. [Register the API application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#register-a-web-api-and-publish-permissions) in order for any client application to acquire an access token for use with the API application.
2. [Grant access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#grant-a-native-or-web-app-permissions-to-a-web-api) by one or more client applications to the API application.
3. Configure the application identifier for the API application as the expected audience for the API middleware.

The [Azure AD B2C: Requesting access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens) article describes how a client application can acquire an access token for use with an API application.